# Access denied for user 'rdonly'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

I've written a PHP application. It worked fine using the root ID with no password. I then changed the password and the PHP code and this worked fine.

I wanted to create a new User 'rdonly' with Read Only access to the database so that no-one knows the root password (embedded in the PHP). I made the changes and got the above error.

I then gave 'rdonly' the same permissions as the root to see if it was a missing permission. Same error.

I've checked similar error messages. One suggested looking at the 'config.php.ini' file. I did but it didn't contain the new password for the root which is odd as the new password works and I get a similar error if I miss out the password.

```
/* config.php.ini */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';      // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

I'm not sure why the ini file is relevant though as XAMPP (3.2.1) seems to let you change the Privileges.

I made the following changes, putting the '%' entry in as I read this meant all databases (excluding 'localhost') so I added the 'Localhost' entry as well. Not sure what the other root entries are all about !

```
rdonly % global                     all-privileges<P>
       % database specific          all-privileges<P> 
rdonly localhost global             all-privileges<P>
       localhost database specific  all-privileges <P>
root   127.0.0.1 global             all-privileges<P>
       127.0.0.1 database specific  all-privileges <P>
root   ::1       global             all-privileges<P>
       ::1       database specific  all-privileges <P>
rdonly localhost global             all-privileges<P>
       localhost database specific  all-privileges <P>
```

(Sorry cant use pictures as a newby)

When I go into 'Admin' on XAMPP it does ask me to sign in, when it didn't when the root password was blank. I cant sign in using the 'rdonly' ID and password.

My code falls over at the Mysql connect statement:

This works:

```
$con=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "mysql");
```

This doesn't:

```
$con=new mysqli("localhost", "rdonly", "password", "mysql");
```

Would be grateful for your advice. Just cant see what the issue is.

Comment: Is the database server hosted on the same server that the script is running on? I'm not an expert, but it appears that you're limiting the rdonly account to connections from localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: The `%` doesn't mean all databases, it means all clients.  Meaning you can login to rdonly from any other system (remotely or locally).  `localhost` means you can only login to rdonly from the same system (locally).  MySQL technically treats these entries as two different users.

Comment: How did you create the rdonly user?  I'm assuming you didn't define the password correctly.  rdonly and root wouldn't just share the same password by default.

Comment: The database is on the same server. I downloaded XAMPP onto my laptop and write the scripts using Dreamweaver on the same Laptop.

Comment: Thanks about the %. Useful to know. I guess just need the % permission.

Comment: I added the 'rduser' using XAMPP. Selected 'Databases', then on the 'mysql' row clicked 'Check Privileges', then 'Add user' and completed the Username, left host as '%' added password, left 'Grant all privileges on database and just 'select' on global privileges. Just repeated the process to set up 'rdo' user. Same error unfortunately. Changing the 'root' password, I just selected the 'root' 127.0.0.1 list and then there is an option 'change password'. I set up 'rdonly' and 'root' with different passwords. Thanks everyone

Comment: I thought phpMyAdmin was part of XAMPP as it loaded at the same time. I've just read that it's not so I should have mentioned I'm using phpMyAdmin to set up the security etc.

Comment: Managed to resolve this and learn a few things along the way. Deleted all users and set just the one up pointing to localhost following the guidance in http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/adding-a-new-user-to-a-mysql-database-in-xampp' Not sure why it didn't work initially but sorted now. Thanks for the advice.